# Conditions with whitespaces in activerecord find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So i am trying to do this

```
Order.find :all, :conditions => "org = 'test     org'"
```

what ends up firing is

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE (org = 'test org')
```

the whitespace in the argument gets stripped. what am i missing.. im really stumped here. please help!

Comment: It's a well documented idiosyncrasy of MySQL where using `LIKE` respects the whitespace where as `=` does not: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First turn on the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) in MySQL and see whether the query, as received and executed by MySQL itself, is correct.

This is because Rails will [squeeze](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000854) all duplicate whitespace from its own query logs (when running in development mode):

```
  # /rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb
  def log_info(sql, name, ms)
    if @logger && @logger.debug?
      name = '%s (%.1fms)' % [name || 'SQL', ms]
      @logger.debug(format_log_entry(name, sql.squeeze(' ')))
    end
  end
```

If the query sent to MySQL, according to the MySql query log itself, is still incorrect, try again with:

```
Order.find :all, :conditions => [ 'org = ?', 'test     org' ]
```

Comment: tried this.. i even tried find_by_sql, tried :conditions => {:org => 'test       org'}

Comment: its the mysql gem. mysql (2.8.1)

i will try updating it. but i have been using the gem for a while.. never had any problem.

Comment: yup.. you were right the information is being queried fine.. the logs are being written like that. thanks.

Comment: Hi , i am having same problem in Rails 3.2.22 but its not happening when i run similar command on rails console with Rails 4. I am not sure if its the thing with version or some other problem . Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with rails, but rather a way that mysql behaves.

For example:

```
mysql> select first_name from users where first_name = "George                    ";
+------------+
| first_name |
+------------+
| George     |
| George     |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's one way to fix it:

```
mysql> select first_name from users where BINARY(first_name) = BINARY("George                    ");
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select first_name from users where BINARY(first_name) = BINARY("George");
+------------+
| first_name |
+------------+
| George     |
| George     |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Good luck!

Comment: This example is using VARCHAR. However I see that it only applies with trailing spaces, so it doesn't fit to the op's example.

Comment: Let us know if wrapping the strings in BINARY() changes anything.